# MySQL Full text search and underscore

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for a way to add additional word separators for MySQL5.7's full text search. Basically would like to tell mysql to consider underscores as comas.
Would **turning underscores into stopwords** work? And how? Any info appreciated.

**Edit**: the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251518/how-to-make-mysql-treat-underscore-as-a-word-separator-for-fulltext-search) is no solution and does not explore stopwords.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make MySQL treat underscore as a word separator for fulltext search?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251518/how-to-make-mysql-treat-underscore-as-a-word-separator-for-fulltext-search)

Comment: That referenced post does not bring any solution, nor explores stopwords.

Comment: Perhaps you couldn't be bothered to scroll down, but the non-accepted answer does show a solution: create a copy of the character map in use and mark `_` as a non-word character.

Comment: That post is talking about adding the dash character, not the underscore character, which is an exception for the stopword list.

Comment: Yeah so it's the reverse of what you want. The dash character is a separator by default, which they didn't want. The underscore character is a word character by default, which you don't want.

Comment: Except you can't add underscore, that's the big issue.

Comment: @Eric did you ever find a solution to this? It would be helpful for me to accomplish the same

Comment: @willsmanley unfortunatelly no

Comment: ok thanks. for anyone else coming upon this, I think the best option is to create a duplicative column - replacing underscores with spaces, or similar. And that one can have the full text index.

Comment: @willsmanley I think we ended up changing underscore with dash...